# "vitest --ui" causing "Error: spawn xdg-open ENOENT"

Tags: node.js, vite, vitest

I'm trying to check out Vitest's fancy [UI server](https://vitest.dev/guide/ui.html) in my node docker container. But can't get it up and running. When running the npm script `vitest --ui` I get a node error `spawn xdg-open ENOENT`.

Here the full error message:

```bash
$ npm run test-ui
```

```
> wpvite@0.0.0 test-ui
> vitest --ui


 DEV  v0.23.4 /home/node/apps/main/frontend
      UI started at http://localhost:51204/__vitest__/

node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn xdg-open ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn xdg-open',
  path: 'xdg-open',
  spawnargs: [ 'https://localhost:51204/__vitest__/' ]
}

Node.js v18.10.0
```

Google is no help at all - nothing related to Vitest even close. Also I'm obviously not a Node.js expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the Node.js error message appears pretty cryptic to me, I still was lucky to use Ubuntu as my primary OS (beside macOS) which made me draw my attention to `xdg-open` in the error message - I occasionally use the command to open all kind of programs/apps on Ubuntu. Don't know why, but you need to have xdg-open installed on your system, to be able to run `vitest --ui`, even though it's neither mentioned in Vitest nor in Vite Github repos with a single word. Anyway for debian based containers it's:

```bash
apt install xdg-utils --fix-missing
```

Allthough this made the ENOENT error go away and the UI server starts up without errors, I still don't get to see the UI app due to some runtime-dom errors... I give it up. But maybe someone else finds the xdg-open info helpful.

## UPDATE: It's working!

I just had to append `/__vitest__/` to my proxied local url as clearly described in the docs:

> "Then you can visit the Vitest UI at `http://localhost:51204/__vitest__/`"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open the FE in a browser, do this:

```
sudo apt install xdg-utils
```

If you don't want to open the UI, like in a server, edit your `package.json` file:

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite --no-open",
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running SveltKit with pnpm, vite, and vitest...

Got the same error message without `vitest --ui` part ...

Solved by running it in docker without "--open"

```
CMD ["pnpm","run", "dev"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app in docker, make sure you `open` set to `false` in `vite-config.ts`

```json
    server: {    
        host: true,
        port: 3000, 
        open: false
    }
```

and `package.json` only has `"start": "vite"` or `"start": "vite --no-open"`